# Batch file running powershell

Tags: powershell-4.0

I have a powershell script to run a msu file

```
Start-Process wusa.exe \\hqfs1\users\tantony\PowerShell\WinUpdate\Win7AndW2K8R2-KB3134760-x64.msu
```

Then, I have a batch file that runs the powershell script

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -noexit "& ""\\hqfs1\users\tantony\PowerShell\WinUpdate\winupdate.ps1""" /quiet /norestart
```

Is there a way to add `/quiet /norestart` in the batch file so that the msu is running silently with no user interaction?

Comment: The parameters seem to already be in the batch script. Are you asking how to pass them to `wusa.exe` in the PowerShell script?

Comment: Yes, I'm asking how to pass them to wusa.exe in powershell script.  I was just testing earlier, and I forgot to take out `/quiet /norestart` before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$update = '\\hqfs1\users\tantony\PowerShell\WinUpdate\Win7AndW2K8R2-KB3134760-x64.msu'
Start-Process wusa.exe ((,$update + $args) -join ' ')
```

Comment: Thank you Ansgar Wiechers, but it still brings up the wusa.exe window.  I'm trying to do a silent install.

Comment: That's what the code does if you correctly pass the parameters `/quiet` and `/norestart`. Please provide evidence.